# Is there a charge between Azure CDN and hosted application in same data center?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I know "There is no charge on bandwidth between Azure storage and applications hosted in the same data center."

And there has 5000 requests/second limit, and Microsoft suggest use CDN to overcome the limits.

So, I like to know "Is there a charge on bandwidth between Azure CDN and hosted application in same data center?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of the CDN as about 2 dozen non-datacenter entities (nodes?). Any time a CDN node is loaded with a requested object, you're paying for egress from blob storage, along with the associated transaction(s) against storage, required to transfer said object to that CDN node. There's no concept of CDN being in the same data center as your hosted app.

Looking at the full picture:

- There's egress cost + transaction(s) for each object loaded into each CDN node (and there's no way to decide how few or how many nodes are loaded; this is based on whichever CDN node a client app ends up hitting, based on various networking rules)
- There's egress cost + transaction(s) for each object transfered from a CDN node to a client application.
- There are no CDN nodes considered "inside a Windows Azure data center" - each node has a load cost associated with it.

Full pricing details are [here](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/).